# functions with parameter a list and standard deviation

Tags: python, list, recursion

Write a class called Person that has two data members - the person's name and age. It should have an init method that takes two values and uses them to initialize the data members.
Write a separate function (not part of the Person class) called std_dev that takes as a parameter a list of Person objects and returns the standard deviation of all their ages (the population standard deviation that uses a denominator of N, not the sample standard deviation, which uses a different denominator).

Must be in python

class Person:

```
def __init__(self, name, age):
    """doc string 1"""
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

def show_person(person_list):
    """doc string 2"""
    for person in person_list:
        print("Name:", person.name, "\t Age:", person.age)

def std_dev(person_list, length):
    """doc string 3"""
    total, mean, sd = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0

for person in person_list:
    total += person.age

mean = total / length

for person in person_list:
    sd += math.pow(person.age - mean, 2)
    return math.sqrt(sd / length)
```

> Test Failed: Failed to import test module: tests Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py",
>   line 428, in _find_test_path
>       module = self._get_module_from_name(name)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in
>   _get_module_from_name
>       **import**(name)   File "/autograder/source/tests/tests.py", line 3, in 
>       from std_dev import std_dev, Person   File "/autograder/source/std_dev.py", line 28
>       return math.sqrt(sd / length)
>       ^ SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: It looks like the last eight lines of code in your snippet should be part of the `std_dev` function, but they aren't. They need to be indented.

Comment: Except the `return` statement at the end is correctly indented, it shouldn't be in the `for` loop.

Comment: BTW, you can write `total = sum(person.age for person in person_list)`

Comment: And `sd = sum(math.pow(person.age - mean, 2) for person in person_list)`

Answer (score 0):

First off, you gotta `import math`

```
import math

class Person:

  def __init__(self, name, age):
    """doc string 1"""
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
```

I don't think `show_person` should be indented inside your person class

```
def show_person(person_list):
    """doc string 2"""
    for person in person_list:
      print("Name:", person.name, "\t Age:", person.age)
```

The same goes for your `std_dev`function. Another thing is that you don't have to take the list length as an argument in the function. We can easily find it with `len(person_list)`as shown below:

```
def std_dev(person_list):
  """doc string 3"""
  total, mean, sd = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
  # No reason to take length of list as argument
  # We can just get it this way
  length = len(person_list)
  for person in person_list:
    total += person.age

  mean = total / length

  for person in person_list:
    sd += math.pow(person.age - mean, 2)
  return math.sqrt(sd / length)
```

Example of running:

```
p1 = Person("Alex", 36)
p2 = Person("Billie", 34)
p3 = Person("Carol", 32)
persons = [p1, p2, p3]
show_person(persons)
print(std_dev(persons))
```

Output:

```
Name: Alex   Age: 36
Name: Billie   Age: 34
Name: Carol    Age: 32

1.632993161855452
```

Hope this helps :)